# On the choice of $\delta$ for $|x-a|< \delta \implies |x-a|+|f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function, and I have to prove that for all $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that:

$$|x-a|< \delta \quad \implies \quad |x-a|+|f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon$$

What $\delta$ should I choose? Does it make sense to choose $\delta=\epsilon +|f(x)-f(a)|$?

Comment: The $\delta$ you choose is not even a number? It depends on $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, we can find $\delta_1>0$, such that $|x-a|<\delta_1$ implies $|f(x)-f(a)|<\frac{\epsilon}2$.

I will leave the task of verifying $\delta = \min(\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \delta_1)$ works to you.